# How can I create a stored procedure in multiple instances in one go / one script?

Tags: sql-server

I have 19 different instances and I want to create a stored procedure which returns all SQL Jobs details. One by one creation is a way to create, well that's good but its time consuming.

Is there any other way to create the stored procedure in all 19 different instances by one single go or one single script?

Sample of my script:

```
CREATE PROC Get_Jobs_Inventory_Detail
AS
    SELECT  
        j.name AS [Job Name],
        j.[description], 
        j.date_created, 
        j.date_modified,
        CASE j.[enabled] 
           WHEN 0 THEN 'Disabled' 
           WHEN 1 THEN 'Enabled' 
        END AS [Job Status]
    FROM 
        msdb.dbo.sysjobs j
    GROUP BY 
        j.name, j.[description], j.date_created, j.date_modified, j.[enabled] 
    ORDER BY 
        j.[enabled]
```

This is my first question in any blog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use registered servers in Management Studio, you can right click on a server group and choose "New Query. The script you run will be run on all servers. This will require some configuration of default database per server registration or creative use on "USE " in the script, but if your instances fit the structure or you already have registered servers configured, this could be rather helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerShell for that one:

```
clear
$instances = (Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Name -like 'MSSQL$*'}).DisplayName
$machine_name = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostName()

foreach ($inst in $instances) {
    $serv = $machine_name+"\"+$inst.Substring($inst.IndexOf("(")+1).Replace(")","")

    $conn=new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection 
    $ConnectionString = "Server="+$serv+";Database=MyDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=0"
    $conn.ConnectionString=$ConnectionString 
    $conn.Open()

    $commandText = "CREATE PROC Get_Jobs_Inventory_Detail
    AS
    SELECT j.name  AS [Job Name],j.[description], j.date_created, j.date_modified,
    case j.[enabled] 
    WHEN 0 THEN 'Disable'
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Enable'
    END AS [Job Status]
    FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs j
    GROUP BY j.name, j.[description], j.date_created, j.date_modified,j.[enabled] 
    ORDER BY j.[enabled];"


    $command = $conn.CreateCommand()
    $command.CommandText = $commandText
    #$command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    $command.ExecuteScalar()

    $conn.Close() 
}
```

This script will get all instances on local machine and run command you need in a loop.

Personally I use PS for that kind of thing, but that could be achieved with **[sqlcmd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx)** or **[BCP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

try this one

Create procedure 
<@param1 , @param2 , etc..> 
as begin

end
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON  to 
GO